# Execute prepared statement in a batch in NodeJS using node-mssql?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, parameterized-query, node-mssql

In java I can send multiple set of parameters of a parameterized query in one go (see code example below).

How can I accomplish the same result in NodeJs, using [node-mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql) package?

```
  PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (?, ?)");
  ps.setString(1, "John");
  ps.setString(2,"Doe");
  ps.addBatch();
  ps.clearParameters();
  ps.setString(1, "Dave");
  ps.setString(2,"Smith");
  ps.addBatch();
  ps.clearParameters();
  int[] results = ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: If you're only looking for batch inserts, `node-mssql` can do [bulk inserts](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#bulk-table-options-callback).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk-table-options-callback - It's there in the documentation.

Comment: I need to performa this using parameterized query, not table object.

Answer (score 1):

You could bulk insert using `request.bulk` method.

This example is `node-mssql` driver package.

> **bulk (table, [options,] [callback])**
>        
> Perform a bulk insert.
>  
>   
> **Arguments** 
>   **table -** sql.Table instance. 
>   **options -** Options object to be passed through to driver (currently tedious only). Optional. If argument is a function it will be treated as the callback.
>   **callback(err, rowCount) -** A callback which is called after bulk insert has completed, or an error has occurred. Optional. If omitted, returns Promise.

**Example:**

```
const request = new sql.Request(/* [pool or transaction] */)

try {
    const table = new sql.Table('employees ') // or temporary table, e.g. #temptable
    table.rows.add(1, "John");
    table.rows.add(2,"Doe");
    table.rows.add(1, "Dave");
    table.rows.add(2,"Smith");

    const request = new sql.Request()
    await request.bulk(table);
} catch(error) {
    console.error(error.message);
}
```

You could read more about bulk insert [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk-table-options-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps.

See if it is useful:

https://blog.stvmlbrn.com/2018/07/27/dynamic-where-clauses-with-parameterized-queries-in-node-mysql.html

Comment: `mysql` <> `mssql`